# QTabBar selector for unread data

Tags: css, qt

I use css style to distinguish tabs in Konsole application:

```
QTabBar::tab:selected {
  background: #4286f4
}
QTabBar::tab:hover {
  background: #dff442
}
QTabBar::tab:selected:hover {
  background: #fd4442
}
QTabBar::tab {
  background: #449449
}
```

Everything works fine including **selected:hover** selector for special color for hover over selected tab. The only problem I can not solve is foreground for a tab which has unread data. Does anyone know which selector to use? Default style conflicts with my color.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "tab which has unread data"?

Comment: I mean I have several tabs in Konsole application. So, imagine I have tab A selected (currently visible in the window) and some output comes to tab B which is not currently visible (now contains unread data). At that moment foreground of tab B changes to some grey color which is hardly readable on chosen background.

Answer (score 0):

I have found at least partial solution to my problem. In the code I have found there is no such state. But the color comes from color scheme ActiveText. I can not make it bold but I can change the color to make it readable at least. So far so good. Potential problem is the color may be used by some other apps...